# Перехват ошибок с `WebView` ios если он присутствует на экране.

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

Мне нужно проверять присутствует ли на экране `WebView`, и если да тогда перехватывать ошибки `JavaScript`. Этот код должен быть имплементирован во фреймворке тоесть не должно быть привязки к определённому `WebView`.

Comment: что уже пробовали?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193119/how-can-my-iphone-objective-c-code-get-notified-of-javascript-errors-in-a-uiwebv и использовал эти библиотеки http://opensource.apple.com//source/WebKit/WebKit-6531.9/mac/WebView/ но насколько я понял они только для Mac os приложения

Answer (score 1):

Проходи рекурсивно все вьюконтроллеры (начиная с window.rootViewController). Ищешь selectedViewController в tabBarController, topViewController в navigationBar, presentedViewController для обычных viewController-ов.
На самом верхнем vc рекурсивно проходишь вьюшки( но только свои), ищешь класс WebView, ставишь ему setScriptDebugDelegate